# sedによる数値の抽出について

Tags: sed

csvファイルに対してcutコマンドを使い、必要な列は切り出して
パイプでsedに渡した後の処理についての質問です。

sed以外でも簡単に実現可能なら、それでも大丈夫です。

下記のようなcsvファイルがあります。

1 boa usa 100
2 soo usa -100
3 soo usa 50
4 boa usa -100

boaかつusaの場合で、数値がマイナスの行だけ抽出する
sooかつusaの場合で、数値がプラス（マイナスなし）の行だけ抽出する

数値以外の項目は完全一致にしたいです。
usaaaや、boaboaなどの文字列を含む行があるので、それは
抽出したくありません。
数値はマイナスが付くか、付かないかの2種類となります。
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: CSVと言いつつ「空白区切り」に見えます。それとも処理対象は「CSVから `cut` で取り出した結果」ということでしょうか。

Comment: 説明不足ですみません。仰る通りcutで取り出した結果でございます。元のcsvファイルはカンマ(,)区切りになっております。

Comment: @cubick さん、補足的な情報ですが、character-separated values で CSV と言うこともあるので、空白区切りでも一概に間違いとは言えなさそうです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

私なら**awk**を使います。CSVから必要な列だけcutで取り出した結果を処理対象として…

- boaかつusaの場合で、数値がマイナスの行だけ

  ```
  $ awk '{ if($2 == "boa" && $3 == "usa" && $4 < 0) print $0 }'
  ```
- sooかつusaの場合で、数値がプラス（マイナスなし）の行だけ

  ```
  $ awk '{ if($2 == "soo" && $3 == "usa" && $4 > 0) print $0 }'
  ```

空白区切りで1列目の値が`$1`、2列目の値が`$2`…と続き、行全体は`$0`で参照します。

(前回の質問でも説明しましたが、`sed`は基本的に文字列の「置換」を行うコマンドです)

Comment: 目的の通りの結果となりましした。抽出はgrepとawkで色々と試して見ようと思いす。sedは置換ですね。ありがとうございました。

Comment: sed を置換だけに使うのは個人の使い分けですね。検索にもよく使われます。

Answer (score 0):

必ず4列で数値にイレギュラーがないなら、sed でも労せず実現できます。

```
sed '-e / boa usa -[0-9]/p;/ soo usa [0-9]/p;d'
```